# Integrate $\int \log(1+2m\cos x+m^2) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-integration

How do I integrate $\int \log(1+2m\cos x+m^2) dx $ ?

I tried 2 things. First, I tried complex numbers. Putting $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} $ which led me to $\int \log((me^{ix} +1)(me^{-ix}+1))dx $ and finally $\int \log(me^{ix} +1)+\log(me^{-ix}+1)dx $ , which I expanded using taylor expansion of $ \log(1+x)$ and then transformed it back to sine and cos, and then integrated but the answer was pretty ugly. And I'm not even sure it is correct.

Another thing I tried was to differentiate the integral with respect to m and then integrate it with respect to x and then with respect to m.  But I couldn't do the last step, id est, integrating with respect to m.

Is there any other method which can be applied for this integration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By exploiting the Taylor series of $\log(1+z)$ in a neighbourhood of the origin,
$$\int \log(1+me^{ix})\,dx = C+i\cdot\text{Li}_2\left(-me^{ix}\right).$$
An interesting possibility is given by differentiation under the integral sign:

$$ \int\frac{2m+2\cos x}{1+m^2+2m\cos x}\,dx = \frac{x}{m}+\frac{2}{m}\,\arctan\left(\frac{m-1}{m+1}\,\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
The integral of $\log(1+m^2+2m\cos x)$ is just the integral of the previous line with respect to the $m$-variable.

Comment: Yes, I did everything that you did but the last line ("the integral of the previous line with respect to the $m$ -variable"), is what I can't seem to do.

Comment: @AritraDas: you may substitute $u=\frac{m-1}{m+1}$. In any case, you have to reach the real part of a dilogarithm. Are you sure the original problem was requesting to compute a primitive for $\log(1+m^2+2m\cos x)$, for *any* $|m|<1$?

Comment: Not even $ |m| < 1 $ but for $ m > 0 $. I think we need 2 cases, one for  $ |m| < 1 $  and the other for  $ |m| > 1 $ .

Comment: This quesiton is from a book, which also lists some hints. There they have mentioned using $ \log(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - .... $ But is this formula applicable for complex values of x ?

Comment: That series is applicable in a region for which $\log z$ is analytic.